# jquery validate validar dos valores en un mismo input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Si podrian ayudarme, estoy usando jquery validate y quiero hacer la siguiente validación:

en un input solo quiero aceptar 0  o  un rago entre 20 y 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que agregar un método de validación personalizado, puedes hacerlo así:

```js
$.validator.addMethod(
    "ranges",
     function(value, element, ranges) {
        var valid = false;

        for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
          if (Array.isArray(ranges[i])){
            if (ranges[i][0] <= value && value <= ranges[i][1]) {
              valid = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          else if (value == ranges[i]) {
            valid = true;
            break;
          }
        }

        return this.optional(element) || valid;
    },
    "El valor no se encuentra dentro del rango permitido"
 );

$( "#form" ).validate({
  rules: {
    rango: {
      required: true,
      ranges: [0, [20, 100]]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
    <p>
      <label for="rango">Rango (0, 20 - 100)</label>
      <input id="rango" name="rango" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias..